# Sql query not returning desired result

Tags: sql

```
ID  Dst Channel                             destination
1                                           123
2                                           123
3   SIP/5raghami-00043236                   91026
5   SIP/5raghami-00043232                   91132
6   SIP/107-00043230                        123
7   Local/123@from-queue-00006326;1         802
```

The following query just prints 6,7. My desired output is 1,2,6,7

```
    SQL = "SELECT id,duration FROM result where destination='123' or (destination='802' and [Dst Channel] like '%Local/123%')"
    RS.Open SQL, con
    while not rs.eof 
        response.write rs("id")
    rs.movenext
    wend
    rs.close
```

I think rows 1 and 2 are ignored because [Dst Channel] is null. Is there any problem with query I wrote? (perhaps problem with prantheses)

Comment: Which dbms do you use?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas No, that should not matter, as the destination being `123` alone should suffice for the `WHERE` clause being true.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ah crap. Yep, you're correct!

Comment: Have  you tried your query in a DB console, i think the query is correcct

Comment: Is destination realy a string not a number type?

Comment: Is it the real query that you pass? You're selecting the duration column but you expect to display the ID column.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48eb8/3

Comment: destination was originally a number in excel file but I put it in a Sql nvarchar field when I read the excel file. @Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query (with some cosmetic changes):

```
SELECT r.duration
FROM result r 
WHERE r.destination = '123' OR
      (r.destination = '802' AND r.[Dst Channel] LIKE '%Local/123%');
```

Your query is doing *exactly* what you intend.  If ids 1 and 2 are not being returned, it is because `destination` contains something other than `'123'`.

The most likely assumption is that `destination` is a string.  If so, it might contain "hidden" characters.  You can check with this version:

```
SELECT r.duration
FROM result r 
WHERE r.destination LIKE '%123%' OR
      (r.destination = '802' AND r.[Dst Channel] LIKE '%Local/123%');
```

Often hidden characters pose as spaces at the beginning or end of strings.  Note that the hidden characters could be in the `LIKE` pattern.

There is a very unlikely scenario where `destination` is a floating or fixed point number that you (or the application) has rounded for the question.  Both floating and fixed point numbers will accurately represent the integer 123.  So, the assumption is that a number close to 123 is stored in the column, but not exactly 123.

Comment: There is the issue of which database is being used, as whether `destination` is perhaps a numeric column, with some implicit casting happening/not happening here.

Comment: This is the case if destination is an string, not an integer. If that's the case, OP has more problems just than that.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . It should not make a difference if `destination` is numeric.  Well, there is the unlikely case that it is a floating point number not exactly "123", but rounded to "123" by the OP for the question.  In other words, floating point representations are accurate for smallish integers; so although not recommended, the conversions should result in the equality being correct.